# @android:id/empty shows empty view, but does not show the ListView when data exists in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a ListFragment with the following layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No data" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the ListFragment is initially created it has no data and everything is fine. The "no data" textview is shown as expected.

But when i add content/data the ListFragment remains in the "No Data" view, and does not switch to showing the rows. If i take out the @android:id/empty portion of the XML then i can see the rows perfectly fine. This means that it is not an issue of inputting data, but an issue regarding the actual XML file (i belive).

Is there any way to remedy this?

**Update: 
Calling notifyDataSetChanged() when adding to the List resolved this issue!**

Comment: Have you checked that your Adapter return 0 on getCount()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you add this code to the fragment, where you set an adapter on the listview?
list.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty)) ?

Comment: what is `list` in this scenario?

Comment: I missed that you were using a ListFragment, which should handle the empty view, but in this case it would be getListView() inside the fragment.

Comment: If this doesn't do anything, perhaps you forgot to call notifyDataSetChanged() when new data has been added?

Comment: Calling notifyDataSetChanged() fixed this issue! Thanks! :)